# Strange behavior on 192.168.6.0 / 24 subnet

Tags: windows-7, subnet

I have a Windows 7 computer running a camera system (Security cameras).
The cameras are installed on 192.168.6.0/24 subnet, and I can't get the computer to connect to the 192.168.6.0/24 subnet. I have tried both static and dhcp.

All other computers work on the 192.168.6.0/24 subnet - I have also tried the cable and switch port!

I have tried to move the computer onto other networks, such as 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24, 192.168.4.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24. All of these work. It's only 192.168.6.0/24 wich I can't get to work on the computer running the camera suite.

What can create this behavior, and how do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

The firewall was not setup to allow traffic from 192.168.6.0/24 subnet.

Comment: I don't understand how this earned a down vote. The OP indicates it was the resolution to their problem.